# URL:'http://reposUrl" does not exist

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, google-code, rapidsvn

I got this error:

```
TortoiseSVN: URL:'`http://reposUrl`" does not exist?
```

When i'm trying to checkout repos:

```
https://code.google.com/p/andro-ftp/source/checkout

http://andro-ftp.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/andro-ftp-read-only
```

or

```
https://andro-ftp.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/andro-ftp-read-only
```

I used rapidSVN and I can not checkout too?

Could you download that repo and upload it for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://code.google.com/p/andro-ftp/source/checkout

The URL you need to checkout is `http://andro-ftp.googlecode.com/svn/`

The project does not have any files in the last revision, BTW.

Comment: update your WC to revision 39, and read docs http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/index.html
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/